# Problem executing algorithm

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, gdal-rasterize

When I run the script below, I got this error:

[image]

```
rps=10000 #RasterPixelSize

layer = iface.activeLayer()
extent = layer.extent()
xmin = extent.xMinimum()
xmax = extent.xMaximum()
ymin = extent.yMinimum()
ymax = extent.yMaximum()

param = {"INPUT": layer,
         "FIELD": "PolygonId",
         "BURN": 0,
         "UNITS": 0,
         "WIDTH": rps,
         "HEIGHT": rps,
         "EXTENT": "%f,%f,%f,%f" % (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),
         "NODATA": 0,
         "OPTIONS": None,
         "DATA_TYPE": 5,
         "INIT": 0,
         "INVERT": False,
         "OUTPUT":"sdx"}

processing.runAndLoadResults("gdal:rasterize", param)
```

Comment: What is `"sdx"`? Did you try using a full path (e.g. `"OUTPUT": "path/to/sdx.tif"`)?

Comment: Yes yes I tried them all: " ", "D:/raster.tif", "raster"

Comment: If your run the algorithm through the toolbox with the same parameters, does it work correctly?

Comment: Yes. When I run it from toolbox it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem:

```
    param = {'BURN': 0.0,
             'DATA_TYPE': 5,
             'EXTENT': "%f,%f,%f,%f" % (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),
             'FIELD': 'PolygonId',
             'HEIGHT': rps,
             'INIT': 0.0,
             'INPUT': fileName,
             'INVERT': False,
             'NODATA': 0.0,
             'OPTIONS': '',
             'OUTPUT': QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition(dosya),
             'UNITS': 0,
             'WIDTH': rps}
```

`fileName` should be path of the vector file.

`QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition(dosya)` should be path of the raster layer with *.tif extension

That's all!